# System.Text.Json.JsonException - Error deserializing

Tags: asp.net-core

Here is my code:

```
   public class Element
    {
        public string? Group { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("small")]
        public string? Sign { get; set; }
        public double Molar { get; set; }
        public IList<int>? Electrons { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Sign} - {Name}";
        }
    }



 public List<Element> LoadJson()
        {
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("jsondata/elements.json"))
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                var ElementObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Element>>(json);

            
                return ElementObject;
            }
        }
```

### elements.json

```
{

  "elements": [
    {
      "group": "Other",
      "position": 0,
      "name": "Hydrogen",
      "number": 1,
      "small": "H",
      "molar": 1.00794,
      "electrons": [
        1
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "Noble Gas (p)",
      "position": 17,
      "name": "Helium",
      "number": 2,
      "small": "He",
      "molar": 4.002602,
      "electrons": [
        2
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

while I am trying to deserialize I get

System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BlazorApp4.Shared.Entities.Element]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 |

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The JSON doesn't represent a `List<Element>`.  It represents an *object* which has a *property* which is a `List<Element>`.

Create that object:

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize into that:

```
var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
return root.Elements;
```